# Convert fetch actions to axios actions

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I'm trying to update my actions to axios from fetch.

For example my current login looks like this:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGES'
    });
    return fetch('/login', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: email,
        password: password
      })
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
            token: json.token,
            user: json.user
          });
          cookie.save('token', json.token, { expires: moment().add(1, 'hour').toDate() });
          browserHistory.push('/account');
        });
      } else {
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
            messages: Array.isArray(json) ? json : [json]
          });
        });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

So far for the conversion to axios, I have this:

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
    // const { email, password } = this.props;

    (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGES'
    })
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/login',
        data: { email: email, password: password }
    }).then((response) => {
        dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
        token: json.token,
        user: json.user
        });
        cookie.save('token', json.token, { expires: moment().add(1, 'hour').toDate() });
        browserHistory.push('/account');
    })
    .catch(() => dispatch({
        type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
        messages: Array.isArray(json) ? json : [json]
        })
    )
}}
```

Its not working :( and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - not too familiar with axios.

I'm getting this error in Google Chrome console

[image]

Comment: What is `json` supposed to be referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is cause you're calling a json variable that is not present in your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the data via **`response.data`**. When using `fetch()` it made sense to convert the response with `response.json()` and use a `thenable` to tap into that `json`, but with `axios`, you can reach into the response right away without any conversions.

```
export const login = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
           type: 'CLEAR_MESSAGES'
        })

axios.post("/login", {email, password}).then((response) => {
    dispatch({
       type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
       token: response.data.token,
       user: response.data.user
    });
    cookie.save('token', json.token, { expires: moment().add(1, 'hour').toDate() });
    browserHistory.push('/account');
})
.catch(() => dispatch({
    type: 'LOGIN_FAILURE',
    messages: Array.isArray(json) ? json : [json]
    })
)
```